# removing the height attribute when binding to resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have done a navigation which goes the full document when mobile view which is done using jquery.

I am trying to cancel the height to be back to auto or just remove the style attribute which was given from the previous jquery.

But for some reason it does not work, I have tried a few things but it simply does not work.

Can you not cancel the style attribute if it is given through jquery?

Here is navigation which opens and closes the navigation in mobile view:

```
// Mobile Navigation Area
jQuery('.menu-icon-mobile').on('click',function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var currentId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var mobileHeight = jQuery(document).height();

    switch (currentId){

        case 'mobile-nav-open':{

            jQuery('.navigation').animate({height: mobileHeight + "px"}, 400 );
            jQuery(this).attr('id','mobile-nav-close');

        }
        break;

        case 'mobile-nav-close':{

            jQuery('.navigation').animate({height: "0px"}, 400 );
            jQuery(this).attr('id','mobile-nav-open');

        }
        break;

    }

});
```

Here is the resize code, ive added the alert to show that its binded and it is :(

```
//checking if the screen is resized and if it is and the screen is less that 768px wide then cancel the attributes
jQuery(window).resize(function(){

    var thescreen = jQuery(window).width();

    if(thescreen > 768){

        jQuery('.navigaiton').removeAttr('style');

    }

    alert(thescreen);
});
```

For what I can see this should work, the only thing I can think of is that the style attribute is not there in real life as its done using jquery so it cant see the style attribute to remove it.

Any idea how to remove the attribute once given?

Here is the jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/robertg/kn1scc2f/2/

Thanks

Comment: Here please check height attribute gets removed http://jsfiddle.net/Aerious/6h30eL8q/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misspelled your selector.

Change:

```
jQuery('.navigaiton')
```

To:

```
jQuery('.navigation')
```

Comment: Did you try `inherit`?

Comment: this did not work either, the style="height:6947px;" is still on the navigation div :(

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: It doesn't work because `jQuery('.navigaiton')` should be `jQuery('.navigation')`

Comment: thanks for finding that, ive been looking at this for more than 2 hours, I cant believe i did not pick that up :( time for a break ...

Answer (score 1):

You can remove any css attribute completely from the markup using the code below

```
    $('your-selector').css('height', '');
```

Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Aerious/6h30eL8q/

Comment: This works please confirm you are using correct selector and create a fiddle for further assistance

Comment: Hi @Aerious here is the jsfiddle as you can see it does not work, for some reason I cant get it to work doing anything :( http://jsfiddle.net/robertg/kn1scc2f/2/